# Firebase database on push get id

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to imitate an insertion trigger on Firebase using the [onWrite](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.database.RefBuilder#onWrite) method. The insertion is done via POST requests since I am testing it (easiest way I found to check database triggers). The trigger includes writing the Firebase generated ID inside the inserted data as a new property.

My cloud function is this:

```
exports.onNewSeries = functions.database.ref('/series').onWrite(event => {
    "use strict";
    console.log(event.data.key);
    console.log(event.data.current.key);
    console.log(event.data.current);
});
```

Both first logs contain the same key (`series`), which actually is the key of the parent node where the new data is appended, instead of the new data key (in the quirky form of `-adfaa123sdfasdf`). The last log prints a Firebase structure containing the new data as well as the generated key in a _data property, however it is not accessible.

While this can be done manually after a request, I have not seen it automated in a database trigger way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the generated key, make the function trigger on a specific child:

```
exports.onNewSeries = functions.database.ref('/series/{id}').onWrite(event => {
    console.log(event.params.id);
});
```

Also see the [Firebase documentation on handling database events](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events).